# React native Unable to resolve module ./flux.png from

Tags: ios, react-native

When I tried the [TabBarIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html#content) example code in a react-native project, It was unable to find the image:

`icon={require('./flux.png')}`,

When I comment out this line, everything works OK.

Below is the react-native console info:

[image: react debug console]!

I have already copy the flux@3x.png to JS folder, But it does not seem to work. Any thought on this problem?

[2]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After goole-ing, here I get the solution:

As the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources) says, the (flux.png) image file needed to placed to somewhere in your source code tree and reference it as below:

`<Image source={require('./flux.png')} />`